# How to disable Gnome Ctrl-Shift-E Emoji popup

Tags: gnome

I am using IntelliJ on Pop_OS. `Ctrl-Shift-E` is bringing up the `Recent Locations` popup in the IDE usually. Since I use Pop_OS it seems that an emoji autocomplete popup of GNOME is overriding this Keystroke in the whole OS.

I'd love to deactivate it to use my IDE properly. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this feature is integrated in GTK3 and is called with Intelligent Input Bus (IBus). So, at the moment, it should be possible to configure it with `ibus-setup`. Just run it from a terminal emulator or from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command prompt, go to "Emoji" tab, click <kbd>…</kbd> button next to the shortcut and clear it in the pop-up dialog.

[image]